# Are there any curse associated with Padmanabhaswamy temple & Sabrimala of Kerala, India?

Tags: history, temple, india, superstitions, curse

[*Padmanabhaswamy kshetra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padmanabhaswamy_Temple) and [*Sabrimala area*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabarimala) are 2 of the most sacred places in the state of Kerala, India.

In recent years, there have been certain controversies associated with them, where the honorable high court and supreme court of India were found intervening.
e.g. certain vaults of Padmanabhaswamy temple were opened or are waiting to be opened<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padmanabhaswamy_Temple#Controversies)</sup>; similarly there are issues with women's entry to the Sabrimala area<sup>[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabarimala#Women_pilgrims)</sup>

It appeared as of that there had to be a reason for such restrictions.
Are there any historical curse involved, which may affect the surrounding areas of these sacred places?

Comment: woman who ages less  than 50 are not allowed. it would create some health problems in womens

Comment: Yes i meant the same.. that u are just expecting that some curses might have resulted those scenarios.. But without any grounds how can one expect that reason responsible are some curses? that's my Q..Imagine if there are no such curses in truth how to answer this Q. @iammilind

Comment: For example if ur Q simply was - What is the religious/spiritual reason responsible for those current happenings? -- then it would have been closed surely. So I am seeing the involvement of the curse angle just as an attempt to make it on topic. @i

Comment: @Rickross, in such case the answer can be, 'there is no historical/mythological curse associated with these places'. But I think, when there is a restriction for any activity, it's always followed by a curse. In Padmanabha, it is probably restricted in opening the gold vaults, while in Sabrimala, women entry is restricted. So when such energy (good or bad) is disturbed, such eventuality may happen. IMO, it's likely to have such curse associated. See [Bhangarh village/fort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhangarh_Fort). BTW, the "curse" angle may not have much to do with on-topic, IMO.

Comment: in such case that can be the answer, that there is no historical/mythological curse associated with these places.  --- But what I am saying is it's impossible to prove such a thing. so no texts will explicitly say that there are no curses associated. At the most the curses list can be given. So if from that u want to draw the conclusion that "No.. curses are not the reason" then that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the secret doors of [Padmanabhaswamy temple](https://theindiantemples.com/padmanabhaswamy-temple/) are such.
Which will never be opened because behind those doors comes the sound of water flowing.
And some priests of the temple also say that if they open the doors, there will be catastrophe in the world.
By the way, these things are not less than a curse.

By the way, if we look at the [Sabarimala temple](https://theindiantemples.com/sabarimala/) as a curse, then this is the biggest curse.
Women are not allowed to enter this temple, whose age is between 10 and 50, they do not get admission in the temple.

Comment: Catastrophic 2020 for e.g?